# Jquery Shopping with jquery ajax cart working only on 1 product(row)

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Good evening maam/sir. I'm working on shopping cart with jquery ajax. my code is working but it only works in 1 product (row) if i change the qty my 2nd product (row) the calculation wont work.

update:i change the jquery from using the ID attribute to class attribute the problem is that the total is displaying in all column not on his selected product quantity.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>Product</th>
  <th>Restaurant</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th class="text-center">Price</th>
 <th class="text-center">Total</th>
 <th> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($cart as $value): ?>


<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
  <div class="media">
  <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" 
  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic- 
  2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
 <div class="media-body">
   <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#"><?php echo $value['product_name'] 
  ?></a> 
  </h4>
    <h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#"><?php echo 
  $value['restaurant_name'] 
  ?></a></h5>
 <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong><?php echo 
  $value['status'] ?></strong></span>
  </div>
  </div></td>
  <td class="col-md-1 text-left"><strong class="label label- 
  danger">None</strong></td>
 <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
 <input type="email" class="form-control qty" id="qty" name="qty" 
 value="">
  </td>
  <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodprice" 
  id="prodprice"><?php echo $value['price'] ?></strong></td>
  <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center" ><strong id="prodtotal" 
   class="prodtotal"></strong></td>
    <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach ?>    
  <tr>
   <td>   </td>
   <td>   </td>
   <td>   </td>
   <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
   <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$999.99</strong></h5></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Estimated shipping</h5></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h5></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
   <td>   </td>
   <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
  <td class="text-right" id="total"><h3><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h3> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
    </button></td>
     <td>

    <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/checkout') ?>"><button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success" >
     Checkout <span class="fa fa-play"></span></a>
     </button></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>


<script>
  $('.qty').on('input', function() { 
console.log($(this).val())
var price =$('#prodprice').html()
var qty = $(this).val();
var prodtotal = price * qty;
$('.prodtotal').html(prodtotal);
var a =$('#totalcart').val()

</script
```

[image: Update: the total is already displaying but in all column not in his selected product qty]

Comment: Hi, show html code as well

Comment: done sir i also added an my update progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.closest("tr")` to get the closest tr from your quantity input then use `.find()` to find your price value and then add the result inside total column

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.qty').on('input', function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr") //get closest tr
  var price = parseInt(selector.find('.prodprice').text()) //get price
  var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
  var prodtotal = price * qty;
  selector.find('.prodtotal').html(prodtotal); //add total in same row
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Restaurant</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th class="text-center">Price</th>
        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic- 
  2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">
                <a href="#">
              Abc
                </a>
              </h4>
              <h5 class="media-heading"> by
                <a href="#">
                Astar
                </a>
              </h5>
              <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong>Good</strong></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 text-left"><strong class="label label- 
  danger">None</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
          <input type="email" class="form-control qty" name="qty" value="">
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodprice">55</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodtotal"></strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic- 
  2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">
                <a href="#">
                Abc1
                </a>
              </h4>
              <h5 class="media-heading"> by
                <a href="#">
                A star 3
                </a>
              </h5>
              <span>Status: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong>ok</strong></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 text-left"><strong class="label label- 
  danger">None</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
          <input type="email" class="form-control qty" name="qty" value="">
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodprice">77</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong class="prodtotal"></strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Subtotal</h5>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <h5><strong>$999.99</strong></h5>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Estimated shipping</h5>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <h5><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h5>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <h3>Total</h3>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right" id="total">
          <h3><strong>$9.999.99</strong></h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
    </button></td>
        <td>

          <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/checkout') ?>"><button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success" >
     Checkout <span class="fa fa-play"></span></a>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thank you so much sir.. now i can finally pass my thesis subject